# Getting stucked starting Jetty until I strike enter

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have an issue with **run-jetty-run** Eclipse's plugin. I use basic configuration, without any changes : no SSL, parentLoadPriority, ...

**Each time I launch it from "Run As > Configuration", server is loading itself but seems to be waiting for something.**

```
Running Jetty 8.1.2 v20120308
ParentLoaderPriority enabled
Context path:/myProject
[lib loading...]
Excluded entry=D:\myProject\workspaces\workspace\myOrg\myProject\target\test-classes 
2012-09-13 15:27:37.868:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-7.6.2.v20120308
2012-09-13 15:27:38.649:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/myProject, file:/D:/myProject/workspaces/workspace/myOrg/myProject/src/main/webapp/]}
2012-09-13 15:27:39.102:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

**When I strike [Enter] about 5 times, it does really start ...** and reply to my external requests (http).

I can reproduce it every time across all my projects vith jetty Running Jetty 8.1.2 v20120308 (and 6.1.26).

But what is very stange is that when I run mvn jetty:run command (so not using the run-jetty-run plugin) this behaviour totally disappear. There must different configuration, but I cannot figure what !

I'm convinced that Maven IS the solution ( ;) )... but not all my company projects are using Maven (indeed very few of them :D)

Can somebody give me a hint ?
Don't hesitate to ask for details.

Comment: The Eclipse Plugin seems to use a different Jetty version 7.6.2.v20120308 - not the ones you expect (8.1.2 v20120308 (and 6.1.26))

Comment: The plugin indeed allow you to use different version of Jetty. The 7.x one don't work for me :). Thanks for your (lonely) answer :)